# How to play audio file from External Storage?

Tags: android, listview, android-sdcard, android-music-player

I am trying to play audio file from external storage but can only click the item from the listview and it does not play. Am I missing any necessary codes. Please help me according to my codes. I have a listview and it retrieves all songs but do not play. For more clear:

## 1. I have a listview with songs retrieved from external storage

## 2. I click on an item but can not play the audio file.

```
import android.Manifest;

import android.media.AudioManager;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import android.net.Uri;

import android.provider.MediaStore;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Build;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.database.Cursor;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.AdapterView;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
int index;
Uri uri;
Cursor cursor;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
ArrayList<String> arrayListSong = new ArrayList<>();
public static final int RUNTIME_CODE = 1;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listViewAudio);
    runtimePermission();
    uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListSong);
    try {
        getSongList();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }catch (Exception e){ e.getMessage(); }
    playOnItemClick();
}

public void runtimePermission() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, RUNTIME_CODE);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, RUNTIME_CODE);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case RUNTIME_CODE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getSongList();
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void getSongList() {

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                arrayListSong.add(cursor.getString(index));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}

public void playOnItemClick() {
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }catch (Exception e) { e.getMessage(); }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Plz show the full code.

Comment: I have only one activity "MainActivity" that I've added in the description. I have no other activity. In this "MainActivity" I implemented for runtime permission, listview and mediaPlayer. But mediaPlayer does not work.

Comment: =======activity_main.xml=======
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewAudio"
        android:outlineProvider="paddedBounds"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml where I added permission.

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>